# Consistent colouring in `ggplot2` when factor levels are (sometimes) missing using `scale_colour_manual` or an alternative

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I have a `df` and a colour palette `cp`:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(1,1,1), col = c(1,2,3), 
        label = c("one", "two", "three"))
cp <- c("#9986A5", "#79402E", "#0F0D0E")
```

I can plot the labels with the corresponding colour from my `cp` with:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_text(aes(label = label, color = as.factor(col)))
  + scale_colour_manual(values = cp)
```

[image]

However, when there are factor levels missing, the colouring gets inconsistent:

```
df$col <- c(1,1,3)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_text(aes(label = label, color = as.factor(col))) 
  + scale_colour_manual(values = cp)
```

[image]

How can I achieve a consistent colouring that is independent from missing factor levels?

Comment: Have you tried ignoring the missing levels when plotting? Alternatively you can impute the missing levels and do the plotting. Or you can just create a data frame with no missing values from the original data frame and do the plotting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a named vector to specify your colour palette, levels will be matched up with colours consistently:

```
cp <- c(`1` = "#9986A5", `2` = "#79402E", `3` = "#0F0D0E")
```

You have to quote the numbers to get them to work as names for the vector.

Answer (score 2):

I found the use of `drop = FALSE` in scale ... manual calls to be really helpful with the problem of unrepresented factor levels leading to inconsistent colour scales.